# Serialized PHP Object not passing via POST.

Tags: php, object, post, serialization

```
     $citation = new Citation();
                    $citation->user_id  =   $result['pmid'];
                    $citation->pmid      =  $result['volume'];
                    $citation->volume    =  $result['volume'];      
                    $citation->issue     =  $result['issue'];       
                    $citation->year      =  $result['year'];        
                    $citation->month     =  $result['month'];           
                    $citation->pages     =  $result['pages'];           
                    $citation->issn      =  $result['issn'];        
                    $citation->journal       =  $result['journal'];     
                    $citation->journalabbrev =  $result['journalabbrev'];   
                    $citation->title          = $result['title'];

                    $string_data = serialize($citation);
```

HTML

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="citation" value="<?php echo $string_data; ?>">
```

Output of $string_data before POST =

O:8:"Citation":16:{s:7:"user_id";s:7:"8046837";s:4:"pmid";s:2:"52";s:6:"volume";s:2:"52";s:5:"issue";s:1:"6";s:4:"year";s:4:"1994";s:5:"month";s:3:"Jun";s:5:"pages";s:6:"1535-8";s:4:"issn";s:9:"0047-1852";s:7:"journal";s:51:"Nihon rinsho. Japanese journal of clinical medicine";s:13:"journalabbrev";s:13:"Nippon Rinsho";s:5:"title";s:46:"[Bronchoscopic classification in sarcoidosis].";s:8:"abstract";N;s:11:"affiliation";N;s:7:"authors";N;s:9:"articleid";N;s:8:"keywords";N;}

And in can be unserialized....

```
                    $new = unserialize($string_data);

                    print_r($new);
```

Gives....

Citation Object ( [user_id] => 8046837 [pmid] => 52 [volume] => 52 [issue] => 6 [year] => 1994 [month] => Jun [pages] => 1535-8 [issn] => 0047-1852 [journal] => Nihon rinsho. Japanese journal of clinical medicine [journalabbrev] => Nippon Rinsho [title] => [Bronchoscopic classification in sarcoidosis]. [abstract] => [affiliation] => [authors] => [articleid] => [keywords] => )

But when I use the checkbox to post to another page, and then

```
    echo $_POST['citation'];
```

I get

Array ( [0] => O:8: )

I have searched Stack for a solution as well as the PHP documentation without success. Does the POST action alter the serialised data in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

First:

```
      $string_data = serialize($citation);

      $string_data = base64_encode($string_data);
```

Then send $string_data using POST

Then

```
      $new_object = unserialize(base64_decode($citation));
```

On the other side...

Comment: I did it w/o base encoding/decoding

Answer (score 0):

I think you should json_encode and json_decode functions

Comment: OK but how it this passed and retrieved via POST in PHP? I can't see nay similar examples to go by. Your opinion is appreciated..

Comment: $param = $_POST['citation'] ;  $citation = json_decode($param)